# Counting a specific char in java, but my program only reads the first character in a word

Tags: java

I have a program that is supposed to count all the instances of a specific character, like 'A', in a specified file. I got it to count the characters, sort of, except it only looks at the character at the beginning of a word. So "a a aaa a ba" would only count as 4 "A"s and not 7. I've commented as best as I can so my train of thought is clear, but I'm fairly new to programming so I apologize in advance if I'm not being clear.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Charcounter
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    //accumulator
    int sum = 0;

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    //get filename and character to be counted from user
    System.out.println("Enter the name of a file: ");
    String filename = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the character to be counted: ");
    char countedChar = kb.next().charAt(0);

    //check if file exists
    File file = new File(filename);
    if (!file.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("File specified not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //open file for reading
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    //read file and count number of specified characters
    while (inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        //read a char from the file
        char count = inputFile.next().charAt(0);

        //count the char if it is the one specified
        if (count == countedChar)
        {
             ++sum;
        }

    }

    //close file
    inputFile.close();

    //display number of the specified char
    System.out.println("The number of the character '" + countedChar + "' is : " + sum);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are only comparing the first character.

```
 //read a char from the file
 // THIS : only the first character
 char count = inputFile.next().charAt(0);

 //count the char if it is the one specified
 if (count == countedChar)
 {
   ++sum;
 }
```

You should loop through all the characters and then increment the sum if it matches the `countedChar`, something like..

```
 String str = inputFile.next()
 for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
   char count = str.charAt(i);   
   // check if it matches the countedChar and then increment.
 }
```

Comment: Much better, I'll remove the comment

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are only reading the first char

```
    String word = inputFile.next();     //read a word
    int counter = 0; 

    for(counter=0;counter<word.length();counter++) // traverse through the word
    { 
        char count = word.charAt(i);       // ith char

        //count the char if it is the one specified
        if (count == countedChar)
        {
             ++sum;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a variable instead of zero which initializes as zero in the beginning of the class and then increment it for every char it counts, so:

```
   //read a char from the file
    char count = inputFile.next().charAt(m);
    ++m;
    //count the char if it is the one specified
    if (count == countedChar)
    {
         ++sum;
    }
```

And then in the main method define:

```
   int m = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using

```
char count = inputFile.next().charAt(0);
```

By default `next` will read until it will find whitespace or end of data so now it reads and returns entire words.

If you want to make this approach work you need `next` to return only one character at a time so set delimiter in `imputFile` scanner to empty string like `inputFile.useDelimiter("");`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    String word = inputFile.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (word.charAt(i) == countedChar) {
            ++sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternative you can use a Reader that is dedicated to char reading:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

int read;

while((read = reader.read())>0) if (read==countedChar) count++;

reader.close();
```